# postgresql: добавить в where содержимое параметра функции

Tags: sql, postgresql, функции, хранимые-процедуры

подскажите, как можно реализовать следующий функционал:

есть хранимая функция

```
myfunc(where_txt TEXT DEFAULT '')
```

внутри функции выборка из таблицы

```
select * from mytable
```

Как сделать так, чтобы если where_txt не пустой, то выполнялся запрос

```
select * from mytable where <содержимое параметра where_txt>
```

иначе просто

```
select * from mytable
```

Comment: Не понял... в параметре будет передано референсное значение, или там будет подготовленное выражение? Если первое - тривиальное `WHERE column = where_txt or where_txt = ''`. Если второе - то тут однозначно динамический SQL, без вариантов.

Comment: там будет подготовленное выражение, например `x = 10 and y = 'xxx'`

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN